# Как в TextView добавить картинку

Tags: swift

Как в `TextView` добавить картинку?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010035/how-to-add-image-and-text-in-uitextview-in-ios

Comment: если какой то из ответов подошел, не забудьте отметить галочкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То же самое, но на Swift 3:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "like after")

let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
textAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "whatever.png")

let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)

attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(4, 1), with: attrStringWithImage)

self.textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

**UPDATE**

Для того чтобы изменить размер вставляемой картинки, можно использовать следующую функцию:

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat, newHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

И в коде выше внести изменения:

```
let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
var image = UIImage(named: "whatever.png")!
image = resizeImage(image: image, newWidth: 50.0, newHeight: 50.0)
textAttachment.image = image
```

Либо можно заведомо использовать картинку меньшего/большего размера.

Comment: А как изменять его размер?

Comment: См. измененный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Через AttributtedString.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"like after"];

NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];

NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 1) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
```